# why does SWIG allow int pointer argument in place of void*, and how to do same for arrays?

Tags: python, c++, swig

I have this class with an `int` and `int[2]` members, and I have a `getMember` accessor method that takes an index of a member and `void*` and fills the (pre-allocated) space after `void*` with the member:

foobar.h:

```
class Foobar {
public:
    void getMember(int index, void* data) {
        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            *(int *) data = member0;
            break;

        case 1:
            *(int*) data = member1[0];
            *((int*) data + 1) = member1[1];
            break;
        }
    }
    int member0;
    int member1[2];
};
```

I can then write a SWIG interface to this:

```
%{
#include "foobar.h"
%}

%include "foobar.h"
```

Now, if I also add

```
%include <cpointer.i>
%pointer_functions(int, intp)
```

I can then do the following in Python:

```
>>>p = new_intp()
>>>f = Foobar()
>>>f.member0 = 2
>>>f.getMember(0, p)
>>>intp_value(p)
2
```

Question 1.  I have a `void*` declared and I am passing `intp` and yet the whole thing works.  Why??

Question 2.  Assuming you explain to me how the above works, then how do I accomplish the same for member1 ?? That is, I added the `pointer_functions` code to make the above work (magically).  Then what similar thing I need to add and what pointer `p1` to pass so that

```
>>>f.getMember(1, p1)
```

works?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I still can't answer Question 1, nevertheless I found the new "magic" way to answer Question 2:

```
%include <carrays.i>
%array_functions(int, inta);
```

Now Question 1 is unchanged, and Question 2 becomes, why does it work?

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to check the code generated by SWIG, but my guess is that for void* function parameter declaration, SWIG can't do any type checking so any type given to the function will be accepted and passed on to the function. Then in the code, you cast the void* to an int* so as long as the type really is an int*, all is good. If you passed something not an int* then you would get undefined behavior such as crash since you would be overwriting part of an object or, worse, a short or such.

So this should tell you that what you are doing is rather dangerous. I don't see why you can declare your function to take an int* since the pointer can refer to one item or an array:

```
void getMember(int index, int* data) {
    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        *data = member0;
        break;

    case 1:
        *data = member1[0];
        *(data + 1) = member1[1];
        break;
    }
}
```

Then SWIG will generate code that will check that the passed-in type is int* and will throw otherwise. I don't know if SWIG will know that your inta type is compatible with intp type. If not,  you could %extend Foo with an adapter in your .i file:

```
%extend Foobar %{
    void getMember(int index, int[2] data) {
        getMember(index, data); // C++ knows this is ok
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, if I pass a wrong type argument, such as, for example, the new_intp() same as above, SWIG does not crash, but does complain about the type.

Comment: With the above soln you get exception by SWIG?

Comment: no, the above works perfectly, I just don't understand it how, that is my question

Comment: please be as specific as possible: what do you not understand? and in question 1, you say "it all works", what works? You said in another comment you get a SWIG warning when you use void*, does that count as "all works"? is it a compile warning then it runs fine?

Comment: I think I am being very clear in my question.  "All works": I quoted a sequence of Python commands showing expected behaviour.  Question 1 (based on the paragraph before it) are very clearly stated.  Not sure why you don't understand it. I appreciate your taking the time to help me.

Comment: No I don't get a warning when I pass void*, there is no way to pass void*, so I don't do that.

Comment: describe what you think should happen instead of what you see.